# Bypass PIA VPN on Hyper-V

Tags: vpn, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 machine with Private Internet Access (PIA) VPN service enabled. I need a Linux instance with direct internet connection, bypassing the VPN. However, all the virtual machines I create in Hyper-V connect through the PIA VPN. The same occurs with Windows Subsystem for Linux instances.

The PIA management app offers a "Split tunnel" feature that allows me to select an application and have it bypass the VPN. I have tried adding ubuntu.exe, wsl.exe and conhost.exe to the list but that doesn't work. Unfortunately, the PIA management app won't go any further than that, so I cannot add the Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter to the exclusion list.

I have contacted the PIA support team but they couldn't provide a solution.

How can I make my Hyper-V or WSL Linux instance bypass the PIA VPN?

Comment: WSL instances run under `WindowsTerminal.exe`, so you may try to exclude it, then run the WSL distribution.

Comment: `"Split tunnel" feature that allows me to select an application` The problem is, traffics from VMs do not originate from a (local) "application" (unless the hypervisor provide the connectivity with something like "userspace NAT", which is not the case of Hyper-V or WSL). Network stack level IP forwarding is what is involved behind the scene. What you need would be alternate routing for some/all forwarded traffics. It is feasible in Linux. Not so sure about Windows.

Comment: @harrymc I don't have Windows Terminal installed so WindowsTerminal.exe is not present in my machine.

Comment: You may exclude whatever is the executable. If unsure, get [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and drag the bullseye icon over the window.

Comment: Could you explain how you've removed/prevented the installation of WindowsTerminal.exe? That is a core function of Windows now, and how you've modified your system may be relevant to finding the correct answer to this problem you're facing.

Comment: @music2myear: The poster might have set *Settings > System > For developers > Terminal* to "Windows Console Host".

Comment: @harrymc does that actually remove WindowsTerminal.exe, or just change the default? This probably isn't relevant, but OPs statement that they don't have it installed makes me wonder.

Comment: Adding to my comment above, the only option you have is probably using an "external" switch instead (i.e., bridge your VM to your LAN). If that for some reason is not acceptable / feasible, then you should give up. (Your gut about "excluding the virtual adapter" makes more sense than the discussion about "process". If you really want to dig deeper, research on whether Windows has unlikely introduced policy routing and multiple route tables in its recent versions / builds. IMHO even that is less wasteful of time.)